# Show / Hide Text preview is showing double

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make my text collapsebel on mobile devices, the problem that i have is that it shows the text where the show more / less button is, double. How can i get it done, that the text doesn't show twice?

Below is the text with the **data-js** attribut, i'm setting the tag, where the show more button should displayed. Problem is that the text *So sind die Hundekissen nicht nur komfortabel gepolstert und so gefüttert, dass der* is double and after the second one it's showing the show more / less button.

```
<p data-js="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
```

This is the JS

```
 // Select all text areas
    var textArea = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js=content]'),    
        maxText = 100;

    // For each one...
    [].forEach.call( textArea, function( el ) {

      var textAreaLength = el.innerHTML.length,
        teaserText = el.innerHTML.substr(0, 100),
        fullText = el.innerHTML,
        showTeaser = false;    

      // Check to see if this text length is more
      // than the max
      if (textAreaLength >= maxText) {
        // Set flag
        showTeaser = false;

        // Set teaser text  
        el.innerHTML = teaserText;
        el.innerHTML += el.innerHTML + '...';

        // Create button
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
        button.classList.add('button');
        el.appendChild(button);

        // Button click event
        button.onclick = function () {
          if (showTeaser === true) {
            // Update flag
            showTeaser = false;

            // Update button text
            this.innerHTML = 'Show Less';

            // Show full text
            el.innerHTML = fullText;

            // Re-append the button
            el.appendChild(this);
          } else {
            // Update flag
            showTeaser = true;

            // Update button text
            this.innerHTML = 'Show More';

            // Show teaser text
            el.innerHTML = teaserText;
            el.innerHTML += el.innerHTML + '...';

            // Re-append the button
            el.appendChild(this);
          }
          return false;
        };
      } else { 
        // Show full text
        el.innerHTML = fullText;
      }   

    });
```

I uploaded to [jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/msadak/pen/pBwKGr) to get a better impression of it

Comment: Can you share any code snippet or working fiddle for more clarifications? Thanks

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add you're code into this

```
 if(window.outerWidth < 991) {
// Select all text areas
// Select all text areas
var textArea = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js=content]'),    
    maxText = 100;

// For each one...
[].forEach.call( textArea, function( el ) {

  var textAreaLength = el.innerHTML.length,
    teaserText = el.innerHTML.substr(0, 100),
    fullText = el.innerHTML,
    showTeaser = false;    

  // Check to see if this text length is more
  // than the max
  if (textAreaLength >= maxText) {
    // Set flag
    showTeaser = true;

    // Set teaser text  
    el.innerHTML = teaserText;
    el.innerHTML += '...';

    // Create button
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
    button.classList.add('button');
    el.appendChild(button);

    // Button click event
    button.onclick = function () {
      if (showTeaser === true) {
        // Update flag
        showTeaser = false;

        // Update button text
        this.innerHTML = 'Show Less';

        // Show full text
        el.innerHTML = fullText;

        // Re-append the button
        el.appendChild(this);
      } else {
        // Update flag
        showTeaser = true;

        // Update button text
        this.innerHTML = 'Show More';

        // Show teaser text
        el.innerHTML = teaserText;
        el.innerHTML += '...';

        // Re-append the button
        el.appendChild(this);
      }
      return false;
    };
  } else { 
    // Show full text
    el.innerHTML = fullText;
  }   

});
}
```

It isn't the cleanest solution, because when someone resizes the browser it wouldn't hide it or show it. The user has to reload his page.

Answer (score 2):

The double text is due to the following code!

```
// Show teaser text
el.innerHTML = teaserText;
el.innerHTML += el.innerHTML + '...';
```

The += reassigns by concatenating the string to result itself and so

`a += a + "..."` is equal to `a = a + a + "..."`

I think you meant to do

```
// Show teaser text
el.innerHTML = teaserText;
el.innerHTML += '...';
```

Also you may want to set showTeaser to True initially since you're hiding text in the beginning!

[Here you go](https://codepen.io/icy121/pen/ROgBRW)

Comment: Thx icy. Helped me a lot. Do u know a way to display this funciton only on mobile devices? For example till a max width of 768? By the way, i updated my jsfiddle with some lorem ipsum text, would be great if you could it too. I forgot it when i posted it, otherwise we would get problems with duplicate content.

Comment: Yes, a dirty way to do that is to monitor change of width as an event and on first load of document. Then check for condition of size and setup your collapsible text. If the condition doesn't match then show full text and hide your button else collapse the text and show the button.
Here's how to use resize event: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp